# Ownership of memory in user-defined classes deriving from Qt classes

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management

I know that, in Qt, parent object takes ownership of its child objects. However, if I have my own class deriving from a Qt class, do I need to control memory in my derived-class' destructor or does Qt do it for me? Below is an example:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class MyWidget: public QWidget{

public:
    MyWidget(QWidget* parent = 0): QWidget(parent) {
        this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        m_button = new QPushButton(this);
    }

    ~MyWidget() { delete m_button; } // do I need this to prevent leaks?

private:
    QPushButton* m_button;

}
```

So my question is, do I need `~MyWidget()` to prevent memory leaks? Or would `QWidget` somehow manage the memory for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you don't, `QObject` handles that. Everything derived will be collected as long as it is in a parent-children tree. `QWidget` inherits `QObject` and you inherit `QWidget`. So you are all set.

Note that there are still many Qt types which do not inherit `QObject`. Better look at the doc to be sure.